# How to share a dynamic link in PHP?

Tags: php, api, dynamic, twitter, hyperlink

I have a generated link in PHP that takes the user's ID and places it at the end of a referral link to track who refers who using a referral system.  Example of the link via php:

```
http://example.com/index.php?page=act/reg&inv=$arrusr[0]
```

I'm trying to create a share button for facebook, twitter, email, and even add a `shortener` using `bitly api` - but I keep running into the same problem... it will not update the user ID, and instead literally send the URL as is.

I'm obviously doing something very stupid.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

How the link is shared:

```
<a class='btn btn-tw' href='https://twitter.com/home?status=http://example.com/test/index.php?page=act/reg&inv=$arrusr[0]'><i class='fa fa-2x fa-twitter twcolor'></i></a>
```

The link works as is.  If I want to just create a simple link, it will give me something like this for example (depending on the user of course):

```
http://example.com/index.php?page=act/reg&inv=43
```

How come, when I use a facebook, twitter, or bitly api share link it refuses to populate the user id on the end of the url?

Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

EDIT (full php code that isn't working)

```
<?php

echo "
        <div class='row'><!-- start of row text -->
            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <center><img src='image/logo.png' alt='Logo' class='img-circle img-responsive logo-size' style='max-height:275px;'></center>
                <div id='DateCountdown' class='img-responsive' data-date='2014-11-01 04:05:00'></div><br />
           </div>
           <div class='col-md-8 welcome-bar'>
                <img src='image/thankyoubanner.png' alt='Thank you for signing up' class='img-responsive'>
                <h2>Invite friends and<br />win more prizes!</h2>
                            <p align='center'>Share this unique link via email, facebook or twitter and win more prizes as each friend signs up.</p>
                            <center><form role='form'>
                            <input class='form-control' id='focusedInput' type='text' value='http://example.com/index.php?page=act/reg&inv=$arrusr[0]' style='max-width:375px;text-align:center;'>
                            </form></center>
                            <a class='btn btn-fb' href=http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://example.com/index.php?page=act/reg&inv=$arrusr[0]'><i class='fa fa-2x fa-facebook fbcolor'></i></a>
                            <a class='btn btn-em' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#subscribe'><i class='fa fa-2x fa-envelope-o emcolor'></i></a>
                            <a class='btn btn-tw' href='https://twitter.com/home?status=http://example.com/index.php?page=act/reg&inv=$arrusr[0]'><i class='fa fa-2x fa-twitter twcolor'></i></a>

           </div>
        </div><!-- end of row countdown -->

";
?>
```

This php is a little box that is correctly generating a copy code (using bootstrap framework), and then the share links that are currently not operating.  (ignore the email link as that's a modal correctly working)

Answer (score 2):

You need to display the id using echo, now you're simply displaying it as static html, nothing else, modify it to

```
<a class='btn btn-tw' href='https://twitter.com/home?status=http://example.com/test/index.php?page=act/reg&inv=<?php echo $arrusr[0]; ?>'><i class='fa fa-2x fa-twitter twcolor'></i></a>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that it was wrapped in a php echo already!  So it essentially looks like this:

<?php

echo "

<a class='btn btn-tw' href='https://twitter.com/home?status=http://example.com/test/index.php?page=act/reg&inv=$arrusr[0]'><i class='fa fa-2x fa-twitter twcolor'></i></a>

";
?>

Comment: @ChrisS Update your question with the way it exactly is in your code

Comment: @Ali sorry. Let me know if I've given you too much or too little.  This is driving me crazy!

Comment: @ChrisS Weird, I couldn't find what was wrong so I ran it through a PHP parser -- http://3v4l.org/UNafD -- It seems to be working fine..

Comment: I checked as well and it should be fine as is, but please check the update to my answer as that should work for sure!

Comment: @ali I realize that it's coded properly, that's why I'm confused also as to why it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

You would want to `echo` that value:

```
<a class='btn btn-tw' href='https://twitter.com/home?status=http://example.com/test/index.php?page=act/reg&inv=<?php echo $arrusr[0]; ?>'><i class='fa fa-2x fa-twitter twcolor'></i></a>
```

---

### UPDATE:

Although it should work as is in your update, please try:

```
<?php

echo "
        <div class='row'><!-- start of row text -->
            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <center><img src='image/logo.png' alt='Logo' class='img-circle img-responsive logo-size' style='max-height:275px;'></center>
                <div id='DateCountdown' class='img-responsive' data-date='2014-11-01 04:05:00'></div><br />
           </div>
           <div class='col-md-8 welcome-bar'>
                <img src='image/thankyoubanner.png' alt='Thank you for signing up' class='img-responsive'>
                <h2>Invite friends and<br />win more prizes!</h2>
                            <p align='center'>Share this unique link via email, facebook or twitter and win more prizes as each friend signs up.</p>
                            <center><form role='form'>
                            <input class='form-control' id='focusedInput' type='text' value='http://example.com/index.php?page=act/reg&inv=".$arrusr[0]."' style='max-width:375px;text-align:center;'>
                            </form></center>
                            <a class='btn btn-fb' href=http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://example.com/index.php?page=act/reg&inv=".$arrusr[0]."'><i class='fa fa-2x fa-facebook fbcolor'></i></a>
                            <a class='btn btn-em' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#subscribe'><i class='fa fa-2x fa-envelope-o emcolor'></i></a>
                            <a class='btn btn-tw' href='https://twitter.com/home?status=http://example.com/index.php?page=act/reg&inv=".$arrusr[0]."'><i class='fa fa-2x fa-twitter twcolor'></i></a>

           </div>
        </div><!-- end of row countdown -->

";
?>
```

by concatenating the value with the string.

Comment: Tried this just now, to no avail.  If I highlight over the link generated for the twitter button, it shows the generated user id at the end of the URL, but once clicked, it's not working.

Any thoughts?  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Probably a `js` library taking over the href before it is executed than, since if you get the right link with the right values than it's not a matter of the generated html as shown in your initial question.

Comment: Perhaps this has something to do with it:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/357750474364812/?comment_id=308955395926697